# How to add bootstrap to yeoman react-webpack?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, yeoman

I am new to modern web development. I am trying to start a project with the react-webpack generator. How do I add bootstrap along with the bootstrap CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-bootsrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) package from npm:

`npm install --save react-bootstrap && npm run build`

Comment: I did that but the bootstrap.css is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add links to bootstrap css in your html. Add the following to the head section of src/index.html:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

See the react-bootstrap docs: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html